# BlackBerry OS upgrade to fix wifi

Tags: blackberry

I am facing an issue with wifi on a Bold 9700 running OS v5.0.0.743.

I have installed an application on a Blackberry 8520 running OS v5.0.0.68 and on a Bold 9700 with OS v5.0.0.743. When I run the app with wifi, I notice that the response from the server comes quickly on the 8520 but the Bold 9700 lags by around 8 seconds.

I have searched for this issue and found out that there is some problem with wifi on the 9700. 
Can this issue be solved by an OS upgrade of the 9700?

Comment: Is this programming related in any way ?

Comment: @Michael : Yes this question is indeed related to programming. Ths same code that is running fine on all other devices is not running properly on 9700. So I think this is related to programming issue. Since this is related to Blackberry development and in BB development we have to support so many devices, therfore such questions do arise.

Comment: if it were programming related, it would not involve upgrading the OS, how many users can you force into that??  it would involve a workaround for the current OS...  just sayin...

Answer (score 2):

about 80%+ of the issues with 9700 wifi are Operator Error

is this an app you wrote?  What did you do to check for available service and connection type within said app?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

I upgraded my device OS to 6.0 and it seems to work fine now.  The issue is with 5.0.0.743 OS.
Thank you all for your responses.